# Unable to cast object of type WhereSelectListIterator 2 System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: linq

I am working on these lists to get an item that matches the selected item from the combobox.

```
private void InitializaMessageElement()
{
    if (_selectedTransactionWsName != null)
    {
```

1. get a transaction webservice name matching the selected item from the drop down here the output=TestWS  which is correct

   ```
   var getTranTypeWsName = TransactionTypeVModel
        .GetAllTransactionTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(transTypes => 
                transTypes.WsMethodName == _selectedTransactionWsName);
   ```
2. Loop the list of wsnames from the treenode list. Here it gives me all the node I have which is correct.

   ```
   var wsNameList = MessageElementVModel
        .GetAllTreeNodes().Select(ame => 
                ame.Children).ToList();//. == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName);
   ```
3. find the getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName in the  wsNameList. Here is where I have the problem:

   ```
         var msgElementList = wsNameList.Select(x => x.Where(ame => getTranTypeWsName != null && ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName)).ToList();
   ```

my MsgElement list:

```
    MsgElementObsList = new ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel>(msgElementList);
    this.messageElements = _msgElementList;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageElements");
}
```

Here it is throwing the cast  error. why is it not working? I am new to LINQ.  thanks

Comment: `.Select(x => x.Where(...))` will return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`.  It's almost definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 26):

As the error is trying to tell you, LINQ methods return special iterator types the implement `IEnumerable<T>`; they do not return `List<T>`.
This enables deferred execution.

Since the object isn't actually a `List<T>`, you can't cast it to a type that it isn't.

If you need a `List<T>`, you can either call `ToList()`, or skip LINQ entirely and use `List<T>.ConvertAll()`, which is like `Select()`, but does return `List<T>`.

Comment: I called ToList() like this   var msgElementList = wsNameList.Select(x =>
                    {
                        x.Where(ame => ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName).ToList();
;
                        return true;

                    });   but the error is the same and how do I do the convertAll ?

Comment: @AydaSayed: You need to call `ToList()` on the object you want to use as a list.

Answer (score 2):

Modify

```
MsgElementObsList = new ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel>((List<MessageElementViewModel>) msgElementList);
```

to

```
MsgElementObsList = new ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel>(msgElementList);
```

This is because although all lists are enumerable, all enumerables are **not** lists, and this one happens not to be one.

Also, your bool error has to do with returning true in the select. Here's the fixed code for that:

```
var msgElementList = wsNameList.Select(x => 
     x.Where(ame => ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName));
```

Comment: I tried that one but it gives me error  cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>' to  System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewModels.MessageElementViewModel>

Comment: here is what i have    var wsNameList =
                    MessageElementVModel.GetAllTreeNodes().Select(ame => ame.Children).ToList();

                var msgElementList = wsNameList.Select(x => x.Where(ame => ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName));

                MsgElementObsList = new ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel>(msgElementList);     but still throw error : cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to System.Collections.Generic.List