# WhereSelectArrayIterator ToList() Results in Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: c#, list, linq, iterator

I am working with a `DataTable` and am trying to select particular elements of rows and create a `List`. My code is as follows:

```
// This is a DataTable
var data = GetUserData(dbPath);

// This is a WhereSelectArrayIterator<DataRow, (int, int)>
var selectedData = data.Select().Select(r => ((int)r["userId"], (int)r[actNum]));

var dataList = selectedData.ToList();
```

At the last line, where I am getting the data as a `List`, an Invalid Cast exception is thrown. I have looked at other questions such as: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151069/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-whereselectlistiterator-2-system-collections-gener), but using the `ToList()` extension method does not seem to work as I had intended, given that `SelectedData` should be an `IEnumerable`.

How do I properly create a `List` from a `WhereSelectArrayIterator`?

Comment: If one of both columns, `userId` or the one with index `actNum` is not an integer(for example a string), then you get the exception.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks! That is what the issue was. The database had been modified and the data type for one of the columns had changed from real to text

Comment: Try using Ienumerable instead of select   From : data.Select().Select(r => ((int)r["userId"], (int)r[actNum])); To data.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new {r.Field<int>("userId"), r.Field<int>(actNum)});

Comment: @pavuxun: makes sense, such things happen with a `UserId`